# Windows phone 7 json .net

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, observablecollection

i have the following response from appengine :

```
{"status":"OK",

  "results":[{

    "field1":"ee2",
    "field2":"ee",
    "field3":0.0,
    "field4":0.0,
    "field5":1990,
    "field6":"dd"}]
}
```

where results is an array.

i would like to parse this into a ObservableCollection using Newtonsoft.Json. Can you help me how to do this ?

Answer (score 2):

i hope this might help: http://www.smallandmighty.net/blog/more-json-with-windows-phone

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

```
var jObject = JObject.Parse(data); //where data is your json response data
var token = jObject.SelectToken("result");
var children = token.Children();
foreach(var child in children)
{
    // Do something with your data
    string field1 = (string)child.SelectToken("field1");

}
```

Hope it helps! Cheers,
/Anders

Answer (score 1):

```
 dynamic Results = new Uri(url).GetDynamicJsonObject();

        foreach (var result in Results.results)
        {                
            string str = result.field1;

            //add to ObservableCollection list 
        }
```